# Detect Keyboard shortcut when computer is locked

Tags: c#, windows, client, locked

Is there a way to detect keyboard shortcuts (For example Ctrl+J+F1) when the computer is locked?

It's actually no problem to do that, when computer is not locked and application is in background (Like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1syNv_Qnio), but I haven't found a way to do that when the system is locked...